# git: Change line ending for specific files and rewrite history

Tags: windows, shell, git

Similar to 
[Rewrite git history to replace all CRLF to LF?](https://superuser.com/questions/293941/rewrite-git-history-to-replace-all-crlf-to-lf)

But just for a couple files in history like: 
    "/path to file/file name with space.txt" 
and 
    "otherPath/other files.txt"

The answers to the linked question change every file in the repository to LF I just want to do it to very few files (3-4 files).

If possible I prefer to use only git tools (because I'm in Windows) like in the answer to the previous question:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --tree-filter 'git add --renormalize .' -- --all
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the `bfg` tool.

```shell
brew install bfg

echo anyword0 >> words.txt
echo anyword1 >> words.txt

bfg --replace-text words.txt .git
```

More info here:
https://www.explainprogramming.com/git/deletion/